# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when wrong folder is chosen in file browser

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have developed something in WPF C#. It browses for a file first in order to make the system works. However if the chosen folder is in the wrong file then it throws an error

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

```
var browse = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
browse.Description = "Select a folder containing *.train files.";
if (browse.ShowDialog() != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    return;
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(browse.SelectedPath, "*.train");           
Array.Sort(fileNames);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What line causes the exception? What does the debugger tell you when you set a breakpoint at that line?

Comment: think your array can be an "empty" / 0 sized array, if there are no .train files in the selected directory....but your later code trying to access the bytes of those files, assumes there is always at least 1

Comment: The code you've posted here works fine for me (and I have no *.train files). Even setting `browse.SelectedPath = null` before assigning `fileNames` didn't throw any exception. Normally `ArgumentOutOfRange` refers to an index in an array. Are you sure you posted the code that's failing?

Comment: Since code in the post does not actually produce the exception the only suggestion is to look into standard duplicate for this type of exception. To get question re-opened please make sure to provide [MCVE] and provide stack trace along with exception info (plus steps you took to debug the problem based on linked duplicate).

Answer (score 0):

```
   var browse = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
    browse.Description = "Select a folder containing *.train files.";
    if (browse.ShowDialog() != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        return;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(browse.SelectedPath))
    {
        string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(browse.SelectedPath, "*.train"); 
        Array.Sort(fileNames);
    }
```

Comment: it still giving me an the same error, but this time its beside the following: <pre> byte[] filepath= result[result.Count - 1].ImageFile; <code>

Comment: show more of your code, as i think the problem is somewhere else

Comment: change your debugger to "Stop on Exceptions", to isolate/find the exact line - see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx